# Anaconda Spyder shortcuts Ctrl+Enter and Shift+Enter are not working

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

Sorry for this noob question. I recently installed Anaconda Spyder UI for Python on MacOS. Within Spyder you see three windows, the python file (source code), the variable explorer and the IPython console.

I got two problems:

First, the shortcuts do not work. For instance: Run Cell = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and Run Cell and Advance is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. But does not work.

Second, the output of the IPython console does not work. Let's assume the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

x
```

Then the last line should print x as output onto the IPython console. But instead I get only this:

> In [1]: runfile('/Users/guest/Development/data.py',
>   wdir='/Users/guest/Development/')

And no Out [1]. **Question:** What am I doing wrong? I couldn't locate anything in the preferences dialog.

Comment: Are you using comments of the form `#%%` to break your file in cells? If you don't do that, then `Cmd+Enter` and `Shift+Enter` don't work. About your second question, if you are running a file with `F5` you need to change your last line to `print(x)` because it doesn't print by default.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. If you post it as an answer, I'll except it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to confirm with you first. I'll rewrite my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use comments of the form `#%%` to break your files in cells, which are blocks of code you can evaluate independently. Then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will work as expected, i.e. they will evaluate the current cell and stay on it or move to the next one, respectively.
2. About your second question, if you are running a file with the Run command (what you get when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>), you need to change your last line to `print(x)`, because Run doesn't print by default.

Comment: by the way: one can type in the IPython console just to print variables to the output. Saves you from using print(x) in code.

Comment: Yep, that's true too.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba you guys shouldn't change stuff like that; this is a high level programming language with an ide build for noobs, let's keep it that way yes?

Comment: If you're talking about cells, the convention I mentioned above is now used in Pycharm and Vscode.

Comment: user12621047 should speak for himself. The cell syntax and usage is great, Carlos.

Comment: does any know if Ctrl + Shift + I and Ctrl + Shift + E are working in latest Spyder 5.4.0?

Comment: @shoggananna, yes, they are working as expected (although that has nothing to do with this).

Answer (score 0):

In IPython console it should work fine. You can try updating your Spyder.

And for shortcuts do not work issue, you can set your own preferred keyboard shortcut from Preference. Customize it by double-clicking on any entry from that table as well as your target action.

> Preference -> Keyboard shortcut

****editor - run selection - Ctrl + Return****

or

****editor - run selection - Shift + Return****